# BF3 Exiting a vehicle - Stage Left or Stage Right?

Tags: battlefield-3

Is there a way to dictate which side of a vehicle you end up on upon exiting said vehicle?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You leave a vehicle into the direction you're looking at. So, if you're in a Jeep and look to the right, you will leave the Jeep to the right.

This feature is - at least for me - not that good. If I am the tank-gunner and - of course - the repair guy, I need to watch to the back of our tank to exit safely. Most of the time you will exit facing the enemy because you just hit the Exit button, but you'll get used to it (or die!) :)

Comment: Great answer! But per the [faq] no signatures please.

Comment: +1 Never realized the direction you were looking mattered, even after playing 180+ hours.

Comment: Me either. Hence the question. 8-D